# iOS Changing SKAction speed in repeating action

Tags: ios, objective-c, skspritenode, skaction

I've read in a few placing that changing the `speed` variable of an SKAction will change the speed; however, that doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
- (void)startAnimating {
    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-[CAUtilities screenSize].height duration:self.animationDuration];
    [self setMoveDownAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveDown]];
    [self runAction:self.moveDownAction];
}

- (void)incAnimationSpeedBy:(CGFloat)aFloat {
    self.moveDownAction.speed += 0.5;
    NSLog(@"%f", self.moveDownAction.speed);
}
```

The actual value of `self.moveDownAction.speed` changes as seen in the `NSLog` call, but the actual animation doesn't change.

I have `incAnimationSpeedBy:` being called when the screen is tapped, so using a `SKAction` sequence with a `runBlock` won't work for my needs.

I've tried:

- Having the initial `moveDown` as an instance variable.
- Having the repeat forever action as an instance variable (seen above).
- Changing the `duration` property rather than `speed`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was trying to change the speed on the different `SKAction` objects when I should have been changing the speed on the parent `SKSpriteNode`.

```
- (void)startAnimating {
    SKAction *moveDown = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-[CAUtilities screenSize].height duration:3.0];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:moveDown]];
}

- (void)incAnimationSpeedBy:(CGFloat)aFloat {
    if (self.speed + aFloat < kMaxSpeed)
        self.speed += aFloat;
}
```